# ettercap not scanning all hosts

Tags: ubuntu, filter, arp, man-in-the-middle

I tried running running ettercap as follows:

```
sudo ettercap -i eth0 -Tq -M arp:remote,oneway -w out.data // /10.8.40.250/
```

But ettercap is able to add only 2 (sometimes 1) hosts to the hosts list.

```
Scanning the whole netmask for 8191 hosts...
* |==================================================>| 100.00 %

1 hosts added to the hosts list...

ARP poisoning victims:

GROUP 1 : ANY (all the hosts in the list)

Starting Unified sniffing...

Text only Interface activated...
Hit 'h' for inline help
```

Why is it only printing group 1?

If I try to poison a particular host,

```
sudo ettercap -i eth0 -Tq -M arp:remote,oneway -w out.data /10.8.41.202/ /10.8.40.250/
```

It works!

my ip: 10.8.57.121 subnet mask: 255.255.224.0

I was able to run the exact same thing some time ago, add 20-30 hosts and successfully ARP poison most of them.
What am I doing wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article about Ettercap & SSLstrip a while ago.(http://bidabe.zapto.org/?p=17)

You are not doing anything wrong, if you run again and again the same command-line you will notice that "**Group 2**" appears erratically.

Using the interactive mode with autoadd, you can see all the hosts (for this subnet) that are being cache poisoned in real-time.
I believe this is a glitch.

[image]